# Central Florida User Group - Feb 26th 2020

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Date/Time (EST): February 26, 2020, 6:30 p.m.

Date/Time (UTC): February 26, 2020, 23:30

Location: Orange County Library, Orlando, FL, 32818

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/Central-Florida-Sitecore-User-Group/events/268544125/

Central Florida Sitecore User Group

Mark your calendars for the next Central Florida Sitecore User Group meeting on Wednesday, February 26th, at 6:30 p.m., at the Orange County Public Library!

We are looking forward to a great meeting! Everyone is welcome and we encourage you to spread the word!

#### Agenda

6:30 – 7:00 Food, Drinks and Social Time
7:00 – 8:45 Sessions to be confirmed
8:45 – Closing comments, end of event

#### Presentations

TBD: Coming Soon